# Is it possible to debug a Kotlin scratch file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, scratch-file

I am attempting to debug a Kotlin scratch file in Android Studio, and I am encountering an issue where the breakpoints are not being hit during the debugging process. The code in question is a simple Kotlin script that implements the bubble sort algorithm:

[image: Bubble sorh algorithm on scratch file]

I have set breakpoints in the IDE, and then I right-clicked on the file and selected "Debug scratch_file.kts." However, the debugger does not stop at the specified breakpoints, and the debugging process seems to bypass them entirely.

Is it possible to debug Kotlin scratch files in Android Studio? If so, what might be causing the breakpoints not to be triggered in this case, and are there any specific steps or configurations I need to follow to successfully debug Kotlin scratch files?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue and have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Were you able to figure out?